# Distance between tangent points of two identical circles internally tangent to a larger circle

Tags: algorithms

This is for a macro to be used in a cad/cam software, and it's purpose is to calculate the stepover distance of a ball nose cutter on a concave surface, based on the cusp height.

I found the attached pic in a google search, but the formula only yields approximate results – the “8” in the formula seems like it can’t be constant. For instance (I checked this by laying it out accurately in Autocad):

Given: Rsurface=.75, Rcutter=.25

When h=.0100”, the “8” needs to actually be 7.919639” to yield the correct S value of .17233295”.
When h=.0075”, the “8” needs to actually be 7.939798” to yield the correct S value of .14943454”.

Again, my ‘correct’ S values were derived by laying the diagrams out in Autocad.

So bottom line; I am looking for a formula more accurate than the attached, to calculate the ‘S’ distance based on the cusp height ‘h’, with the Rsurface & Rcutter values being known (Rsurface=concave surface radius, Rcutter=insert radius).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBlPp.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solving the system of equations

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
 R (R-2 r)& =& (R-\delta ) (R-x-\delta) \\
 d& =& 2R\sin(\theta)\\
 r \csc (\theta )& =& (R-x-\delta) \csc (\psi ) \\
 r \csc (\theta )& =& (R-r) \csc (\theta-\psi ) \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

we get at

$$
d = \sqrt{\delta(2R-\delta)(2r-\delta)(2(R-r)-\delta)}\left(\frac{R}{(R-\delta)(R-r)}\right)
$$

with

$$
d = \ \ \mbox{Sought distance}\\
R = \ \ \mbox{Larger circle radius}\\
r = \mbox{Cutter radius}\\
\delta = \ \ \mbox{Cusp height}
$$

I hope this helps. Attached some results

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
R & r & \delta & d\\
 0.75 & 0.25 & 0.0075 & 0.149435 \\
 0.75 & 0.25 & 0.01 & 0.172333 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$